# Ansible debug variables as a list

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to list the available security patches as a list, but only get the names
for example:

```yaml
name: python_patch33.21
name: java21.21.2
```

However when I get run the results I get:

> 16:10:47  [0;32m{'results': [{'envra': '0:kernel-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64', 'name': 'kernel', 'repo': 'rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms', 'epoch': '0', 'version': '3.10.0', 'release': '1160.80.1.el7', 'yumstate': 'available', 'arch': 'x86_64'}, {'envra': '0:python-perf-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64', 'name': 'python-perf', 'repo': 'rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms', 'epoch': '0', 'version': '3.10.0', 'release': '1160.80.1.el7', 'yumstate': 'available', 'arch': 'x86_64'}, {'envra': '0:tzdata-2022f-1.el7.noarch', 'name': 'tzdata', 'repo': 'rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms', 'epoch': '0', 'version': '2022f', 'release': '1.el7', 'yumstate': 'available', 'arch': 'noarch'}], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}[0m

This is my Ansible task

```yaml
    - yum:
        list: updates
        update_cache: true
        exclude: kernel*
        security: true
      register: yumoutput
    
    - name: Show result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ yumoutput.results }}"
```

Comment: Do I need to use "state" when listing?

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"List the available security patches."***

A: Set `list: sec`. For example in CentOS 8

```yaml
    - yum:
        list: sec
        update_cache: true
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  out:
    ansible_facts:
      pkg_mgr: dnf
    changed: false
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    results:
    - arch: noarch
      envra: 0:sec-2.9.1-1.el8.noarch
      epoch: '0'
      name: sec
      nevra: 0:sec-2.9.1-1.el8.noarch
      release: 1.el8
      repo: epel
      version: 2.9.1
      yumstate: available
```

---

Notes:

- The option [list sec](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021) is not explicitly documented in Ansible [yum](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#parameter-list)
- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: test_24

  tasks:

    - yum:
        list: sec
        update_cache: true
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out
```

```yaml
PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [yum] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  out:
    ansible_facts:
      pkg_mgr: dnf
    changed: false
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    results:
    - arch: noarch
      envra: 0:sec-2.9.1-1.el8.noarch
      epoch: '0'
      name: sec
      nevra: 0:sec-2.9.1-1.el8.noarch
      release: 1.el8
      repo: epel
      version: 2.9.1
      yumstate: available

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: The output is not like a list, but flattened :13:08:15  [0;32mok: [40.118.86.58 -> 172.16.5.7] => {}[0m
13:08:15  [0;32m[0m
13:08:15  [0;32mMSG:[0m
13:08:15  [0;32m[0m
13:08:15  [0;32m{'results': [{'envra': '0:kernel-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64', 'name': 'kernel', 'repo': 'rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms', 'epoch': '0', 'version': '3.10.0', 'release': '1160.80.1.el7', 'yumstate': 'available', 'arch': 'x86_64'}, {'envra': '0:python-perf-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64', 'name': 'python-perf', 'repo': 'rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms', 'epoch': '0', 'version': '3.1

Comment: ok I see the difference is between "msg" and just "var", but how do I select only "name attribute"?